# Logical explanation for '高を括る'? phrase

Tags: expressions

Just came across this phrase and upon breaking it down it looked like it would have the opposite meaning to what it really has (高を括る-to make light of). Have I missed something and there's actually a good explanation for this phrase? My first thought was that it would mean 'to expect a lot' or something similar.

Comment: It look like 括 can mean "constrict". Does there need to be more to it?

Comment: @flowsnake the dictionary I checked says the meaning of 括る here is 予想する, so I'm not sure "constrict" plays a part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

高【たか】 means "yield/amount/quantity" (e.g., of a crop). くくる means "to bind/tie" and, by extension, "to summarize/consolidate". Thus, the literal meaning of 高をくくる is nothing more than something like "to estimate (the capability of someone/something)" or "to assume". However, as an idiom, it has gained a derived *implication* of "to (wrongly) estimate/assume", and that's why "to make light of something" is a valid translation. When it comes to idioms, you cannot expect their literal meanings are preserved.